# Knockout Viewmodel in Typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

How are we supposed to declare viewmodels in typescript?

As classes, modules or as var/functions?

In the definitelytyped examples they use var and function mostly https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout/tests/knockout-tests.ts

EDIT: Thank you Basarat - in this edit I extend the question:
If I use class I suppose it should be like this:

```
class Player
{
    min:KnockoutObservable<number>;
    constructor(min:number=0)
    {
        this.min=ko.observable(min);
    }
}
```

BUT how should computed be defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use computed with generics (latest Typescript 0.9), just define type in declaration and in constructor you will assign value to result of call to ko.computed:

```
export class Inbox extends vm.BriskIdeaViewModel {

    public rapidEntryText = ko.observable<string>();
    public todosActive: KnockoutComputed<Array<ITodo>>;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.todosActive = ko.computed(() => {
            return _.filter(this.dataContext.todos(), x => !x.isDone());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use public and why the () in the end at rapidEntryText = ko.observable<string>()? (I know observables are functions but VS underscores it as an error)

Comment: public is just personal preference - it is same ase without public (typescript is by default public unless you make it private).

Comment: and rapidEntryText = ko.observable<tring>(); is to have default value - you could just separate this assigment to constructor (like for this.todosActive), but this is much easier.

Comment: and basically, you cannot do same with computed in my example, because it references 'this' and in that case you cannot use field assigment as with rapidEntryText

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use classes since they really encapsulate functionality extremely well.

e.g. a simple class :

```
class Player {
    min = ko.observable(0);
    sec = ko.observable(0);
    mil = ko.observable(0);
}
```

And then do a simple apply:

```
    var vm = new Player();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: I've been waiting for someone (other than me :P) to model ko observables with generics - they seem tailor made for it. Have you tried this at all?

Comment: @JcFx Nope. I did do significant generic work though: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections I *very* much prefer AngularJS over knockout. All the knockout I know is now a year old :) AngularJS is now second nature for me :)

Comment: Not to hijack your answer, but hopefuly to add to its usefulness, someone has: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/441964

Comment: Thank you, but should it not be like: class Player{min:KnockoutObservable<number> constructor(min:number=0){this.min=ko.computed(min)}}

Comment: correction 'ko.computed(min)'='ko.observable(min)' Also edited the question to reflect this